# Determining running time of algorithm

Tags: performance, algorithm, recurrence

I've been trying to determine the asymptotic running time for the following made up-algorithm.

Both algorithms Alg-1 and Alg-2 take as input and generate an array with n entries.

Alg-1 would be

```
ALG-1(A[1,...,n])
1: B= ALG-1(A[1,...,⎿n/2⏌])
2: C= ALG-2(A[⎿n/2⏌+1,...,n])
3: return ALG-2(B,C)
```

I'd like to determine the asymptotic running time of ALG-1, considering that running time f(n) of ALG-2 is Θ(√n).

I'm trying to build the recurrence for the algorithm and then solve it via Master theorem but I don't even know how to start. I'd be happy if someone could help me out a bit with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `T_k` denote the time it takes to run `ALG-1` on input of size `n = 2^k`. I'm going to assume that your `ALG-2(B, C)` means `ALG-2` run on the concatenation of `B` and `C`, which is of length `n`. Then, it looks like you have the recurrence

```
T_k = T_{k - 1} + sqrt(n / 2) + sqrt(n) = T_{k - 1} + C * sqrt(2^k),
```

where `C` is a constant. If you keep expanding that out by writing `T_{k - 1}` in terms of `T_{k - 2}`, etc., you get

```
T_k = C * sqrt(2^k) + C * sqrt(2^{k - 1}) + C * sqrt(2^{k - 2}) + ...
```

This is a geometric series, so the sum is of the same order as the leading term (basically, the first term is about as large as the sum of all the remaining terms). So `T_k` is of the order `sqrt(2^k)`, or `sqrt(n)`.

Comment: thanks for the answer but now I'm kind of confused. I was thinking the recurrence would look sth like T(n)= 2(n/2)+ n, since we're dividing the the array into two subarrays and we go through all n elements 1 time. how do you get (k-1)?

Comment: You make a good point in that possibly when you pass the data into ALG-2, it takes O(n) time even if the algorithm itself only takes O(sqrt(n)) time (e.g. consider something like binary search, which only takes O(log n) time on size n input). However, this can usually be avoided by passing the data by reference, i.e. just pass a pointer rather than copy the whole array.